# Enlightened Badge - When does it get awarded

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges

It was my assumption that you received an enlightened badge for every accepted answer with 10 or more points. Is this true? If it is true then why didnt I receive another enlightened badge?

I should have 2 enlightened badges, one for each of these answers

[document.getElementById vs jQuery $()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery/4070010#4070010)

[Preventing SQL Injection in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018174/preventing-sql-injection-in-asp-net-vb-net/4018203#4018203)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only get it if yours is the *first* answer posted, and is accepted with 10 upvotes.  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/146318) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You do have the badge for the one question where you answered first

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened?userid=254528

On the other question, you were not the first answer...